# Spring order of inner bean creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have beans multiple beans that relies on each others. I am trying to figure out what I am doing is the write way to do it? I need to make sure the creation order will be followed etc. Also, if there is a better or alternative way to do it. Thanks

```
@Bean
public BeanA getBeanA(){

 return BeanA();
}

@Bean
public BeanB getBeanB(){

 return BeanB(getBeanA());
}

@Bean
public BeanC getBeanC(){

 return BeanC(getBeanA(), getBeanB());
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using Spring `@DependsOn` annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way will be as follows. Let DI take the control of wiring for you.

```
@Bean
public BeanA getBeanA(){
 return BeanA();
}

@Bean
public BeanB getBeanB(BeanA beanA){
 return BeanB(beanA);
}

@Bean
public BeanC getBeanC(BeanA beanA, BeanB beanb){
 return BeanC(beanA, beanB);
}
```

The whole point of DI is to provide it the objects and declare the dependencies and let it figure out ordering of bean creation and wiring properly.

Comment: That rewrite has absolutely no impact on the creation order of the beans ... care to elaborate why you think this is more "correct" than what OP does?

Comment: @meriton the order of creation will be evaluated by dependency injection framework Spring here at runtime. A will be created first and then B and then C. Why is this correct because here you create single instance of BeanA, BeanB, BeanC and you let DI wire it up for you that is the whole idea of DI. In Op's approach they are creating objects by hand (via calling methods explicitly)

Comment: Actually, Spring's `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor` overrides `@Bean` methods to perform a lookup in the `ApplicationContext`. Therefore, as far as the ApplicationContext is concerned, it doesn't matter at all whether you have Spring autowire parameters of the `@Bean` method, or fetch the dependencies by invoking other `@Bean` methods. The Spring team documents both approaches, and, as far as I know, has not expressed that one is "more correct" than the other.

Comment: Thanks for all answers/comments. But is there another way instead passing them as params? such getBeanB(BeanA beanA).

Comment: Would you want BeanA & BeanB registered into DI or you just want the BeanC into your DI?

Comment: I want BeanA and BeanB to be registered in DI, and get the same instance each time I need them. Register once and use whenever/wherever I need

Comment: So you do not want BeanC entirely registered into DI. correct?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want all of those beans to be registered in DI. Also, what if I want to use BeanC in my tests and pull it from my springconfig class. that time I have to pass BeanA and BeanB as params to getBeanC. Would this be a problem?   Such, in my test class. BeanC beanC=springConfig.getBeanC(here I have to pass BeanA, and BeanB);

Comment: 1. For all the beans to get registered into DI my answer;c code is what you need. 2. Everytime you want to use this bean somewhere you do not have to call `springConfig.getBean(...)` instead you `Inject` the bean into the place you need at, Please go through DI basics here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dependency-injection